# Error installing FreeTDS while Installing both UnixODBC and FreeTDS on a Mac

Tags: macos, freetds, unixodbc

I am on a Mac version 10.12.6. and installing via the terminal window.

I am following this tutorial:
https://www.tonylabs.com/sql-server-note-install-unixodbc-and-freetds-for-mac/

I have installed unixodbc using

```
brew install unixodbc
```

I uninstalled my previous version of freetds using

```
brew uninstall freetds
```

I am now am attempting to reinstall freetds using

```
brew install freetds —with-unixodbc
```

I am getting this error:
Error: No available formula with the name "—with-unixodbc"

Does anyone have any thoughts on what I might be missing?

Comment: Please disregard.  After I pasted in the error and hit submit I noticed the problem.  I had a long dash in front of the with instead of a short one.  Easy fix.  :)

Comment: Ah, the dreaded `emdash` - happens to all of us. Post it as an answer to your own question! :)

Answer (score 0):

My problem turned out to be a typo.  I had a single long dash instead of two short ones.

Corrected:

```
brew install freetds --with-unixodbc
```